# Testing Android App with Alfa and Beta in Google play

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I'm testing an update of my app, and the Alfa / Beta system of Google Play make me crazy!!!

First, I create a group: myapp.alfatesting@googlegroups.com

Then I directly invite users here.

The first problem is it is very common that user has several google accounts, so, you can't tell that the mail you added is the mail he use in Google Play.

Then, once they are invited, they receive a link by mail with a blue button " I want to become a tester", they click it.

Then when I go to Google Play with a tester's email, I should find the new Alfa version, but I still find the old one ( the old production one )

What I am doing is phisycally sending APK to my users, but it is not the best way to do...

Any Idea of what is the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you can't receive the newest version? Is the newest version compatible with your device? Maybe they made changes so that your device is no longer supported in that version.

Comment: nop, I just added Microphone permission... Sometimes I get it working, but I really can't see a pattern and the cause of that...

Answer (score 0):

If it is an alpha, the link should be provided in the email to the user.  They should use that to access the 'Alpha' published apk.